# SQL to check continuous timeline assignment

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

We have 2 tables which have many to many relationship and these can be simplified to :

M-Plan Table with important attributed as M_Plan_ID :

```
M_Plan_ID
VM-000001
VM-000008
```

Grant Table has Grant IDs with Effective Dates:

```
GID             START_DATE      END_DATE    ACTIVE_TIME_LINE
VG-000813       21/04/2018      28/04/2019  Y
VG-000808       29/04/2019      22/04/2020  Y
VG-000800       23/04/2020      18/04/2033  Y
VG-000812       19/04/2033      31/12/9999  Y
VG-000811       22/08/2018      NULL        N
```

And relationship table depicts the Grants assigned to M-Plan :

```
M_Plan_ID       GID
VM-000001       VG-000813
VM-000001       VG-000812
VM-000008       VG-000813
VM-000008       VG-000800
```

The business requirement is that if more than one grant assigned to M-Plan then all assigned grants must be continuous in dates.

And we need to write SQL which would display only missing Grants intervals to M-Plan :

For example VM-000001 has been assigned grants VG-000813 and VG-000812 but missing intervals are VG-000808 and VG-000800.

Similarly, VM-000008 has been assigned VG-000813 and VG-000800 nut missing interval is VG-000808.

The desired result would be :

```
M_Plan_ID  GID
VM-000001  VG-000808
VM-000001  VG-000800
VM-000008  VG-000808
```

The same tables and data can be generated by below statements :

```
create table M_Plan_ID (M_Plan_ID varchar(100)  );
insert into M_Plan_ID(M_Plan_ID) values('VM-000001');
insert into M_Plan_ID(M_Plan_ID) values('VM-000008');

create table grants (gid varchar(100), start_date date, end_date date, active varchar(1));
insert into grants values ('VG-000813',cast('2018-04-21' as Date),cast('2019-04-28' as Date),'Y');
insert into grants values ('VG-000808',cast('2019-04-29' as Date),cast('2020-04-22' as Date),'Y');
insert into grants values ('VG-000800',cast('2020-04-23' as Date),cast('2033-04-18' as Date),'Y');
insert into grants values ('VG-000812',cast('2033-04-19' as Date),cast('9999-12-31' as Date),'Y');
insert into grants values ('VG-000811',cast('2018-08-22' as Date),null,'n');

create table rel  (M_Plan_ID varchar(100), GID varchar(100) )
insert into rel values('VM-000001','VG-000813');
insert into rel values('VM-000001','VG-000812');
insert into rel values('VM-000008','VG-000813');
insert into rel values('VM-000008','VG-000800');
```

The SQL I am trying is something like this :

```
select
T.*,
case when start_date=lead_end_date_1 then 'True' else 'False' end
from
(
select 
M.M_Plan_ID, 
G.GID, 
G.start_date,
ISNULL(DATEADD(D, -1,LEAD(G.start_date) over (partition by M.M_Plan_ID order by g.start_date)), cast('9999-12-31' as Date)) as lead_end_date_1,
count(*) over(partition by M.M_Plan_ID) as count_partition_M_Plan_ID
from M_Plan_ID M
join rel R on M.M_Plan_ID=R.M_Plan_ID
join grants G on R.GID=G.GID
) T
where count_partition_M_Plan_ID>1
and lead_end_date_1!='9999-12-31'.
```

But with this I am only able to get the point where continuity is breaking and we need to see only all missing intervals.

Would appreciate your help in SQL.

Thank You

Comment: What query have you tried so far and where are you finding an issue? It looks like write me a code question.

Comment: Oracle or SQL Server or generic SQL?

Comment: Hi Kaushik Nayak, Added the details in question. I thought there could be totally different approaches in answers. Thanks

Comment: @LukStorms : This for SQL server but even Oracle SQL is provided, I can try convert to sql server

Answer (score 0):

The SQL (MS Sql Server) below filters out the active plans from possible other plans.
Within the existing intervals.
And also filters out those that start too late or end too early compared to the current active plans.

```
with ACTIVEPLANS AS (
    select p.M_Plan_ID, g.GID, 
    g.[START_DATE], 
    coalesce(g.[END_DATE], cast('9999-12-31' as date)) as [END_DATE],
    min(g.[START_DATE]) over (partition by p.M_Plan_ID) as MinStartDate,
    max(coalesce(g.[END_DATE],cast('9999-12-31' as date))) over (partition by p.M_Plan_ID) as MaxEndDate
    from M_Plan_ID p
    join rel r on (p.M_Plan_ID = r.M_Plan_ID)
    join grants g on (g.GID = r.GID and g.active = 'Y')
)
select p.M_Plan_ID, g.GID
from M_Plan_ID p
join grants g on (p.M_Plan_ID <> g.GID and g.active = 'Y')
where not exists (
    select 1 
    from ACTIVEPLANS gp
    where gp.M_Plan_ID = p.M_Plan_ID
      and (
            gp.GID = g.GID
            or (gp.[START_DATE] >= g.[START_DATE] and gp.[END_DATE] <= g.[END_DATE])
            or gp.MaxEndDate <= g.[START_DATE]
            or gp.MinStartDate >= g.[END_DATE]
      )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the grants don't overlap here. My approach is to first figure out what the start and end of the date range for already assigned grants is for each plan (the CTE PlanRange calculates that).

Once I have that, I can then use **CROSS JOIN** to include all grants for the specified date range for each plan. That gives the grants that should be assigned to each plan. After that, it's easy enough to do a **LEFT OUTER JOIN** to the already assigned grants and then only include the grant where there isn't already an entry in **rel** (i.e. R.M_Plan_ID IS NULL)

See: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/787f0/8)

```
WITH PlanRange AS (
    SELECT
        M.M_Plan_ID
    ,   MIN( G.start_date ) AS start_date
    ,   MAX( G.end_date ) AS end_date
    FROM
        M_Plan_ID AS M
    JOIN
        rel AS R ON (R.M_Plan_ID = M.M_Plan_ID)
    JOIN
        grants AS G ON (G.GID = R.GID)
    GROUP BY
        M.M_Plan_ID
)
SELECT
    M.M_Plan_ID
,   G.GID
FROM
    M_Plan_ID AS M
JOIN
    PlanRange ON (PlanRange.M_Plan_ID = M.M_Plan_ID)
CROSS JOIN
    grants AS G
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    rel AS R ON (
        R.M_Plan_ID = M.M_Plan_ID
    AND R.GID = G.GID
    )
WHERE
    G.active = 'Y'
AND G.start_date BETWEEN PlanRange.start_date AND PlanRange.end_date
AND R.M_Plan_ID IS NULL
ORDER BY
    M.M_Plan_ID, G.GID
```

Comment: Thanks Nik, Much appreciated your help on this. Let me translate this to our SQL. Thanks